# Backspace not working for IE Toolbar

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer-8, toolbar

I am developing the Internet Explorer Toolbar in c#.net using the band objects.

Now in my toolbar, I am using the textbox field to make the search enable, but in this textbox field, I am not able to use the backspace, delete, arrow keys and many other such button.

I am not sure about y I am not able to use this. Please help me about this. I found many question posted over like this, but none of them was having the specific answer.

Thanks

Comment: Hard to tell what's wrong. You didn't post any code. Internet Explorer already has a toolbar, you don't need to make a new one.

Comment: TranslateAcceleratorIO is the method you need to override, but you should not build browser extensions in C# for reliability and performance reasons.

Comment: @EricLaw-MSFT Can you please Guide me about what code i must right in TranslateAcceleratorIO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the browser is eating the events for those keystrokes, so the solution is to force focus to the toolbar when the text box receives focus.

To fix it add this line to your toolbar's constructor:

```
yourTextBox.GotFocus += (sender, args) => OnGotFocus(args);
```

Also make sure you have implemented `TranslateAcceleratorIO()` per [this example](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/dotnetbandobjects.aspx?select=1113574&df=100&forumid=3788&noise=1&mpp=50&fr=51).

Answer (score 0):

Compare your code to [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/IE_toolbar.aspx) and see what's missing.